# Given 2 N-ary trees, what could be done better and efficient than pre-order string comparison to show that one tree the subtree of another?

Tags: typescript, tree, traversal, preorder

In a question I am given 2 binary trees, and to check if one binary tree is a subtree of another the code snippet basically does a pre-order traversal on bother trees and generates respective strings. Then it uses indexOf to check if the one tree string is in another to prove that one tree is a subtree of another. 
Now the questions says, since String generation and comparison is expensive, how would I change it to be for n-ary trees besides performing a string comparison.

I'm not sure how to approach the question, but I have an idea where I think I might use a HashMap of some sort to store the tree nodes as keys and its children as values. Then Maybe compare the two tree values on the similar keys to check if the tree is a subtree?

But how does one to that? I'm confused! need a little help.

here the snippet of the functions:

```
//make the Node
interface Node {
  value: string ;
  left?: Node ;
  right?: Node ;
}
function checkSubtree(T1: Node , T2: Node ): boolean {
  return PreOrderTraversal(T1).indexOf(PreOrderTraversal(T2)) > - 1 ;
}
function stringFromPreOrder(tree: Node ): string {
  if (!tree) {
    return "" ;
}
  return tree.value + PreOrderTraversal(tree.left) + PreOrderTraversal(tree.right);
```

So basically given this, how can I make it work better for nary tree instead on concatenating strings and comparing them?
Also, for nary tree, I do know that the children would be in an array and I do preorder on that instead of left and right. But, how can I avoid string concatenation since its expensive?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you provide some code which prove how far did you try? It will help others members to understand your specific problem and the context of your issue as well.

Comment: @GileadKenzo sure yea. 
I'll edit the post and post the snippet of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: https://leetcode.com/articles/introduction-to-n-ary-trees/

You can convert n-ary to binary tree and vice versa.

We already have an algorithm to find subtree of a binary tree.
Refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-binary-tree-is-subtree-of-another-binary-tree/

I am not sure this is a good approach. Just thought of sharing.